# Proving a sequence is bounded under given conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, derivatives, continuity, alternative-proof

This question was asked in [ISI BStat / BMath entrance exam](https://www.isical.ac.in/~admission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGB-2018.pdf):

> Let $f :\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such
>   that its derivative $f'$ is a continuous function. Moreover, assume
>   that for all $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$, $$0\le |f'(x)| \le \frac{1}{2}$$ Define
>   a sequence of real numbers $\{ a_n \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ by: $$a_1 =1,
>  \\ a_{n+1}= f(a_n) \text{ for all } n\in\mathbb{N} \text{.}$$ Prove
>   that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is bounded.

---

My attempt:

If $a_{k+1}=a_{k}$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$, then $f(a_{k+1})=f(a_{k}) \Rightarrow a_{k+2}=a_{k+1}=a_{k}$. Likewise then for all $n\ge k$, we will have $a_{n}=a_k$. Thus, the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is constant eventually, hence, is bounded.

Now, we may assume $a_{k+1}\ne a_{k}$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$. For any $n \ge 3$, we claim that $|a_{n}-a_{n-1}|\le \frac{1}{2} |a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}|$. We prove it as follows: Note that $|a_n - a_{n-1}| = |f(a_{n-1}) - f(a_{n-2})|$ and by the Mean Value Theorem, we can find $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(a_{n-1}) - f(a_{n-2})|=|f'(c) (a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})|= |f'(c) | |(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})| \le \frac{1}{2} |(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})|$. This proves our claim.

Now, for $n \ge 3$, we have $|a_n| = |a_n - a_1 + a_1| \le |a_n - a_1| + |a_1|$. We will try to obtain an upperbound for $|a_n - a_1|$.

$$
\begin{align}
|a_n - a_1| &=|(a_n - a_{n-1}) + (a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}) + \ldots + (a_3 - a_2) + (a_2-a_1)| \\
&\le |a_n - a_{n-1}| + |a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}| + \ldots + |a_3 - a_2| + |a_2-a_1| \\
&\le \frac{1}{2^{n-2}} |a_2-a_1| + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} |a_2-a_1| + \ldots + \frac{1}{2} |a_2-a_1| + |a_2-a_1| \\
& = \left( 1+ \frac{1}{2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{2^{n-2}} \right) |a_2-a_1| < 2|a_2 - a_1|
\end{align}
$$
Thus,we showed that $|a_n| < 2 |a_2 - a_1| + |a_1|$ for all $n\ge 3$. Thus, $\{ a_n \}$ is bounded.

---

**Though, it looks to me that my proof is correct but I have failed to use the fact that $f'$ is a continuous function. Are there any flaws in my proof? Alternative proofs are welcome.**

Comment: Your solution is correct and continuity of $f'$ is not needed. The solution that came to my mind when I read the question was exactly your solution!

Comment: Note that last equality follow from $|a_n| = |a_n - a_1 + a_1| \leq |a_n - a_1| + |a_1|$ step previously said

Answer (score 2):

If $|f'(x)|$ is bounded by $L$ then $f$ is Lipschitz with constant $L$. Here we have $L=\frac{1}{2}$ and so $f$ is a contraction mapping. The Banach fixed point theorem says that $x_n = f(x_{n-1})$ has a unique fixed point and the sequence $x_n$ generated this way is convergent and thus bounded.

Comment: The question says "Proving a sequence is bounded under given conditions" and in the body of the question the author has written, in bold, **"Alternative proofs are welcome."**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This exam is intended for high school students and I doubt that the exam takers would be familiar with Banach fixed point theorem.

Comment: Another question: Is the $f'$ continuous condition necessary?

Comment: You've basically redone the proofs for the theorems I have invoked. Your application of the mean value theorem is exactly how one can show that bounded derivative implies lipschitz continuous. I just skimmed your last argument and I don't see any error.